# Iterating through a hash table of hash tables to display in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hash, iteration

I have a hashtable where the keys are IDs corresponding to a model, and the values are either "none", or another hashtable with the same properties as above. Each model has a field, which is an array of more IDs of another model, which can also have an array of other IDs as a field, and so on (a tree). I wrote a function that iterates through the linked models and creates a hash table of the IDs.

Here's an example of the hashtable:

```
{301=>{304=>"none", 305=>{500=>"none", 501=>"none", 502=>"none"}, 306=>"none"}, 302=>"none", 303=>{400=>"none", 401=>"none", 402=>"none"}}
```

Where the model with ID: 301 has a field: [304,305, 306], and the model with ID: 305 has a field: [500,501,502].

I need to write a function that will help to display the names of the model corresponding to these IDs, in a tree like structure (expandable/collapsable menu will work). Where would I write this function in my rails project to be able to use it in my view file?

This is not just iterating through a hash table, I need to display the names of each model in my view file.

Comment: I will have no problem writing the function that will loop through the hash table. I just have no clue where to put it so I can use that function in my view file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions that you want to call from a view would be stored in your helper files... for example `app/helpers/applicaton_helper.rb`

It would look like...

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def parse_my_hashes(this_hash)
    ... # your code here
  end
end
```

You can then call this helper in your view.

```
<%= parse_my_hashes(@some_hash) %>
```

If you need more information than just the hash, you can pass more to the function as additional arguments.